# Trying to determine file types

Tags: php

I would be glad if you help me with this PHP code .

I made an upload form which only supports `.pdf` , `.docx` and `.rtf` files . 
the file gets uploaded but it can't determine if the file type is pdf , docx or rtl or just non of them . Any solutions to fix this?

well I did a few searches in stackoverflow , some of the members did same as i do but mine still doesn't work. 
This code gets a file from an input . It uploads the file to server , on a specific folder , and then it saves the file's name on database.

```html
  <?php
  function query($q)
  {
    $dbconnection = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1' , 'root' , '');
    $database = mysql_select_db('hire_requests');
    mysql_set_charset("utf8",$dbconnection);
    $res = mysql_query($q,$dbconnection);
    mysql_close($dbconnection);
    return $res;
  }
  function test_input($data)
  {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }
  $error = '';
  $alarm = false;
  $success = false;
  $changedname = '';
  $name = '';
  $lastname = '';
  $phonenumber;
  $nnumber;
  $type ='';
  $mail = '';
  $resume;
  $type = '';
  $notify = '';
  $nameErr= "";
  $mailErr = "";
  $resumeErr = "";
  $nnumberErr = "";
  $lastnameErr = "";
  $phonenumberErr = "";
  $notsentErr = "";
  $sizeErr = "";
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
  {
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
    $phonenumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phonenumber']);
    $nnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nnumber']);
    $mail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);
    if(isset($_FILES['resume']))
    {
      $filename = $_FILES['resume']['name'];
      $filesize = $_FILES['resume']['size'];
      $filetype = $_FILES['resume']['type'];
      $filetmp = $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];
      if($_FILES['resume']['error'] !== 0)
      {
        $alarm = true;
      }
      $AllowedTypesArray = array('docx' , 'rtf' , 'pdf');
      $changedname = 'Rayka_' . rand(1000,9000) . '_' . '5SV4DFS_A245DFA' . '_' . time() . '_' . $name;
      $info = pathinfo($filename , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

      if($alarm = true)
      {

      }
      if($filetype == 'application/pdf' )
      {
        $type = '.pdf';
      }
      if($filetype == 'application/msword' )
      {
        $type = '.docx';
      }
      if($filetype == 'application/rtf')
      {
        $type = '.rtf';
      }
      if(!$type)
      {
        $resumeErr = "file's type is not supported";
      }
      if(!in_array($info , $AllowedTypesArray)) //checks if filetype is pdf , rtl or docx and also , checks if the file is less than 2 mbs or not .
      {
        $error = "file's type is not supported";
        $alarm = true;
      }
      if($filesize > 2097152)
      {
        $sizeErr ="Your file must be less than 2 Mbs";
      }
      $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/_ufile/'.$changedname . $type;
      var_dump($path);
     if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'] , $path) )
      {
        $alarm = true;
        $notsentErr = 'File was not sent';
      }
    }
    if(!isset($_FILES['resume']))
    {
      $resumeErr = 'attachment is not chosen';
      $alarm = true;
    }
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
            {
                if (empty($_POST["name"]))
                {
                  $nameErr = "Enter your name";
                }
                else
                {
                  $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                }
            }
            if(empty($_POST['lastname']))
            {
              $lastnameErr = "Enter your last name";
            }
            else {
              $lastname = test_input($_POST['lastname']);
            }
            if(empty($_POST['phonenumber']))
            {
              $phonenumberErr = "Enter your phone number";
            }
            else
            {
                $phonenumber = test_input($_POST['phonenumber']);
            }
            if(empty($_POST['nnumber']))
            {
              $nnumberErr = "Enter your second phone number";
            }
            else
            {
              $nnumber = test_input($_POST['nnumber']);
            }
            if(empty($_POST['mail']))
            {
              $mailErr = "enter your email address";
            }
            else
            {
              $mail = test_input($_POST['mail']);
            }
          if((!$nameErr) && (!$lastnameErr) && (!$mailErr) && (!$phonenumberErr) && (!$nnumberErr) && (!$notsentErr) && (!$sizeErr))
          {

            $query = "INSERT INTO users (`id`,`name`, `lastname`, `phonenumber`, `nnumber`, `mail`, `resume`) VALUES (NULL , \"$name\",\"$lastname\",\"$phonenumber\",\"$nnumber\",\"$mail\",\"$changedname\")";
            $notify = "Successful";
            $success = true;
            $insert = query($query);
            $error2 = mysql_error();
          }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: This can't be the full script you are using?! What's in $filetype?

Comment: Yeah its actually just a part of it .
filetype is actually this :   $filetype = $_FILES['resume']['type'];

Comment: Well I will post the whole script.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can help http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-buffer.php  using finfo_buffer() function.

Answer (score 1):

Here what i use (i changed for you needs) :

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = finfo_file($finfo, $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name']);
$ok = false;
switch ($mime) {
    case 'application/pdf':
    case 'application/msword':
    case 'text/pdf':
    case 'application/rtf':
    case 'application/x-rtf':
    case 'text/richtext':
    case 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document':
        $ok = true;
        break;
    default:
        die();
}
```

Here the complete mime type list : https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/

Comment: This is the approach I would follow.  Very important word of warning though: MIME types do not prove the file is what it claims to be.  I can call myself French, even though I'm English.  Do not ever assume MIME is correct in a security context.  PDFs and docx files are two of the more commonly attacked formats for evil payloads - so in addition to any MIME checks, I'd strongly recommend a virus scan and/or conversion to image etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time MaximeK . I guess using die(); avoids the  rest of the code from running

Comment: @SinaR - http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Comment: As @wally said, you cannot trust at 100%. But using `finfo_file` is the best practice.